# How to change or decorate actionbar in swipetab?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, swipe

I'm doing SwipeTab android project. (picture below)
[image]

So how can I replace Tab1,2,3 by another icon?
And how can I change color or decorate action bar?
My code here:

```
actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(this));
    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Add icon in this manner, using `setIcon` method

```
 actionBar.addTab( actionBar.newTab()
                                    .setText(null)
                                    .setIcon(R.drawable.activity)
                                    .setTabListener(this));
```

Comment: @PLorida accept the answer, so it can help the others who refers

Answer (score 0):

You can setup icon as follows ,

```
            actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(your text)
                        .setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(<your icon>))
                        .setTabListener(this));
```

And you can change the color by as follows, 
Create a color xml including defined color and put that into drawable folder.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <color xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:color="color code">
 </color>
```

then  -  for action bar only

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(file name));
```

for tabs only

```
actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(file name));
```

Comment: I just need change color of the action bar bro :(

Comment: I try and it changed Title bar ?I need change tab bar bro @@

Comment: check, this is what you asking for :)